# Wijmo grid - Prevent row selection when clicking on a specific column

Tags: jquery-ui, wijmo

I have a Wijmo Grid which allows row selection, whenever a user click on any column.
And I added a column to display a tooltip with additional info of the specific record. 
The problem is when this column is clicked, Wijmo automatically selects the current row.

I've read the documentation, there is no event before selecting a row or clicking on a row. The `selectionChanged` event is not useful in this case, because it is fired after selecting a row.

I cannot add a tr click event handler and make  `e.preventDefault,` because in this case the tooltip would not appear.

How could I prevent row selection, depending on the column clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this. What you could do is, handle the currentCellChanging event and set the 'selectionMode' option to none based on the clicked cell.

```
var isLoaded = false;
$("#gridview2").wijgrid({    
loading: function (e, args) {
   isLoaded = false;
},
loaded: function (e, args) {
   isLoaded = true;
},
currentCellChanging: function (e, args) {
   if (isLoaded) {
      if (args.cellIndex == 5) {
         $(this).wijgrid({ selectionMode: 'none' });
      }
      else {
         $(this).wijgrid({ selectionMode: 'singleRow' });
      }
   }                    
}
});
```

Comment: Actually this will cause all rows to be selectable or not. I'd like to maintain selected rows, if any. On a similar scenario, I'd like to disable row selection on rows according to certain data value. Is this possible? I've been reading the entire Wijgrid Api and the Wijmo Grid posts, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use selectionMode="none" work fine
which not select anything by default